# How can I overload an operator on created pointer object from template class?

Tags: c++

I created a template class which named with Matrix. I'm trying to figure out how to implement an operator+ overload for a pointer which is pointed an Matrix object. My object is scalar matrix operations. I want to add an integer value to each cells on the matrix. I could not understand what is going on my code. The templates have confused me a lot.

"m1" is my Matrix object. When I use `m1 = m1+2`, I'm getting segmentation fault error.

I have tried many different combinations, but I get the same error all the time.

- I tried without a pointer.
- I tried typing **int** instead of **T**.
- Instead of directly returning `new Matrix <int> (10,10,2)`, I tried:

```cpp
Matrix <int> * m = new Matrix <int> (10,10,2)
return m;
```

- When I delete second `m1->print();` statement in main function, the "segmentation fault" error disappears, but every time I try to print I get an error again.

My Matrix class:

```cpp
template <typename T> 
class Matrix{
    vector< vector<T> > matris;
public: 
    Matrix(); // 10x10 matrix with zeros
    Matrix(int width, int height, int value); 
    void print();

    Matrix* operator+(T value){
        return (new Matrix<int>(10,10,2)); // 10x10 matrix filled with 2
    }
};
```

My main function:

```cpp
int main(){
    Matrix <int> *m1 = new Matrix <int>(); // 10x10 matrix with zeros
    m1->print(); // it succesfully shows the elements
    m1 = m1 + 2; // whenever I tried this, I get "Segmentation Fault"
    m1->print();

    return 0;
}
```

My print() function:

```cpp
template <typename T> 
void Matrix<T>::print(){
    for(int h=0; h<matris.size(); h++){
        for(int w=0; w<matris[0].size(); w++){
            printf("%4d", matris[h][w]);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Segmentation fault
```

My expectation is that the assignment was successful, but I get the segmentation fault error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This `m1 = m1 + 2;` just adds `2` to `m1` in arithemtic pointer. It would work if you had array of matrices, but you have only one Matrix instance allocated. You overloaded `operator+` for `Matrix` not `Matrix*`, so it should look like `m1 = *m1 + 2`;

Comment: Be aware that you *cannot* overload arithmetic operators for pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```
 m1 = m1 + 2;
```

the overloaded `operator+` is not used. That is just pointer arithmetic. After that, `m1` points to memory that you don't own. Accessing members of `m1` after that causes undefined behavior.

You can fix that syntactically by using

```
 m1 = *m1 + 2;
```

but it has its own problems. When you do that, the original memory `m1` was pointing to is lost to your program. You have a memory leak.

Providing the overload as

```
Matrix* operator+(T value) { ... }
```

is not idiomatic. Perhaps you want to use:

```
Matrix operator+(T const& value) const { ... }
```

A better alternative would be to use couple of non-member function overloads:

```
Matrix operator+(Matrix const& m, T const& value);
Matrix operator+(T const& value, Matrix const& m);
```

With that, you can use:

```
Matrix<int> m1;
Matrix<int> m2 = m1 + 10;
Matrix<int> m3 = 30 + m1;
```

More on operator overloads can be found at [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)